# Resize Outlook Form Region

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

When I found out that I couldn't control the expanding/collapsing of the form regions, it made me sad. I decided to look into controlling how much the form pops out. This has made me sadder still. It seems that while I can control the height, the user won't be able to set the height *higher* than what I set it to. I couldn't find a height property that controls just how far the region is set without changing the actual height of the form. I'm guessing it's somewhere in the `this.OutlookFormRegion`, but I haven't had any luck. Any direction towards solving this would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can hide the entire form region by doing FormRegion.OutlookFormRegion.Visible = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use the [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._formregion.form(v=office.14).aspx) property of the FormRegion class to set up the required properties?

There are a lot of limitations exist with form regions. The [Creating Outlook Form Regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) section in MSDN describes form regions in depth.

I'd suggest using [Advanced Outlook Form Regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-regions/index.php) instead. They allow to manage the form in the way you need - hide/show, collapse, change the size and layout at runtime and etc.

Another approach is to subclass an Outlook window and inject your own custom form. See [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) and [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) sample project.

Answer (score 1):

If your `FormRegionType` is `Adjoining`, after changing to your form region's e.g. `Height` property, call `this.OutlookFormRegion.Reflow()` to request that Outlook redo form layout. At least that works well for me in Outlook 2013.